# Can iOS app updates be stalled to specific date?

Tags: iphone, ios, appstore-approval

I've been googling this question, but haven't been able to find an answer. 
I know that you are able to upload an app, get it approved, and then set a release date.

But I was wondering if the same thing can be done for an existing app?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what do you mean an existing app? Like an app you already have live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't peg an update to a specified date, but you *can* "hold for developer release" on the update. That means that once it's approved, Apple won't publish the update until you go into iTunes Connect and manually press a button to release it.

Answer (score 0):

No, when you remove an app from sale, you have to put it back manually, there's no way to specify a date to make this happen automatically. See the [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) FAQ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that resetting the release date to the future after the application has been released will take it back out of the store and release it again. Im not sure how apple will look upon this if the application has already been released and is live. Mine was new and I had to keep pushing off the release date because the services were not reliably functional.